# Converting COBOL PIC format to SAS Non Native Machine

Tags: sas, cobol, mainframe

It's more of a reminder for me to understand how the **COBOL PIC formats are applied while reading them in SAS**. What will be the equivalent format in SAS for example X(2) will be $ebcdic2.

- 9(6)
- S9(1) C3
- S9(11)V9(2) C3
- S9(12)V9(5) C3
- S9(9)V9(6) C3
- X(2)

Comment: Where are you running SAS (OS)?

Comment: Good question. SAS EG is running on Windows while the Grid is on Linux.

Comment: Linux would be the relevant OS, then.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should look here: http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts642.html

This is a document from SAS themselves, and it is entitled "Reading EBCDIC Files on ASCII Systems".

The most important advice from that is:

> The only way to overcome the problem of non-standard numeric data being corrupted by the FTP is to move the data without translating it.
>   This will necessitate making some significant changes in your program.
>   It may also require preprocessing the data file on the mainframe. The
>   sections below list the different types of files and situations, a
>   recommended approach to read in the file, and a sample program to
>   accomplish the task.

This is because binary fields and packed-decimal fields are not byte-oriented data. They cannot be converted at the byte level from EBCDIC to ASCII.

Get all the data from the Mainframe provided to you in "character" format (no "COMP" or "COMPUTATIONAL" fields (which means COMP, COMP-1, COMP-2, COMP-3, COMP-4, COMP-5, BINARY or PACKED-DECIMAL)). Then you will have no problems.

There are many questions related to this if you look at those with the PACKED-DECIMAL tag, for instance.

Comment: Unfortunately I am forced to convert them before pulling them in the native format. Very true that Translation will make significant changes which will change the format.

Comment: You should push for whoever is providing you with the file to do the conversion to character from any computational fields. Hold the signs separately, fixed, scaled or explicit decimal place (whichever suits you best). Then, with everything in character format, the EBCDIC to ASCII is unproblematic. On the Mainframe, it is a simple utility (SORT for instance) and done. At most a simple COBOL program. There's no need for anyone to leave you twisting in the wind on this.